# Add custom html to nodes in d3 js tree

Tags: d3.js, tree

I'm trying to build a tree like [d3 js tree](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033). I need to add a div and 2 or 3 buttons in that div for each node of the tree. Clicking on that node button should show a popup.

I'm trying for this kind of functionality
There are [other plugins similar to this](http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_local&view=local&Itemid=73&lang=en). But i need this in d3 js tree as its navigation and animations are smooth.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Anything in particular you're struggling with?

Answer (score 2):

I have done this:

- Use base example from D3 tree web page.
- Added more SVG elements in the nodes
- Added a "popup" menu when you click the node text (Add, Remove, Edit, Move) to perform this simple operations on the node.

In my experience, it is better to use SVG elements instead of a DIV (You can display buttons as images or shapes, and text as svg:text.

Here is some code:

```
function clickLabel(d) {

// this removes the popup if it was displayed on another node beforehand
// is=2 identifies markers... 

d3.selectAll("[marker='2']").remove();

// Every node has an ID, and I add shapes to it

d3.select("[id_node='" + d.id + "']")
    .append("image")
    .attr("marker", 2)
    .attr("xlink:href", "/Content/delete_item.png")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -50)
    .attr("height", 32)
    .attr("width", 32)
    .on("click", removeItem);

d3.select("[id_node='" + d.id + "']")
    .append("image")
    .attr("marker", 2)
    .attr("xlink:href", "/Content/edit.png")
    .attr("x", -50)
    .attr("y", -30)
    .attr("height", 32)
    .attr("width", 32)
    .on("click", editItem); 

d3.select("[id_node='" + d.id + "']")
    .append("image")
    .attr("marker", 2)
    .attr("xlink:href", "/Content/add_item.png")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("height", 32)
    .attr("width", 32)
    .on("click", addItem);


d3.select("[id_node='" + d.id + "']")
    .append("image")
    .attr("marker", 2)
    .attr("xlink:href", "/Content/next_item.png")
    .attr("x", -30)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("height", 32)
    .attr("width", 32)
    .on("click", moveItem);

// Stop events or else it gets de-selected
event.stopPropagation();
```

}

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use     `.append("svg:foreignObject")` to add custom html to nodes in d3 js tree, for example [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vasis1986/md4ud930/19/)