# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to run this demo shared by Igor from this post: [Add custom html to nodes in d3 js tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995202/add-custom-html-to-nodes-in-d3-js-tree). I've made some changes to reflect the new version of D3 below, but I get the above error. I can't find where the error is happening and was wondering if someone could help me figure it out :)

```js
var treedata = {
  "name": "PublisherNameLongName",
  "id": "id1",
  "type": "type0",
  "addable": false,
  "editable": false,
  "removable": false,
  "enableble": false,
  "children": [{
    "name": "Landing A",
    "id": "id2",
    "type": "type1",
    "addable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "removable": true,
    "enablable": true,
    "enable": false,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Account 1",
      "id": "id3",
      "type": "type2",
      "children": [{
        "name": "tracking link 1",
        "id": "id4",
        "type": "type3",
        "enablable": true,
        "enable": true
      }, {
        "name": "tracking link 2",
        "id": "id5",
        "type": "type3",
        "enablable": true,
        "enable": true
      }, {
        "name": "tracking link 3",
        "id": "id6",
        "type": "type3",
        "enablable": true,
        "enable": false
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Account 2",
      "id": "id7",
      "type": "type2"
    }, {
      "name": "Account 3",
      "id": "id9",
      "type": "type2"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Landing B",
    "id": "id8",
    "type": "type1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Account 4",
      "id": "id10",
      "type": "type2"
    }, {
      "name": "Account 5",
      "id": "id11",
      "type": "type2"
    }, {
      "name": "Account 6",
      "id": "id12",
      "type": "type2"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Landing C",
    "id": "id13",
    "type": "type1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Subtopic 7",
      "id": "id14",
      "type": "type3"
    }, {
      "name": "Subtopic 8",
      "id": "id15",
      "type": "type3"
    }, {
      "name": "Subtopic 9",
      "id": "id16",
      "type": "type3"
    }]
  }]
}

var m = [20, 20, 20, 20],
  w = 800 - m[1] - m[3],
  h = 600 - m[0] - m[2],
  i = 0,
  r = 800,
  x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, w]).range([0, w]),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, h]).range([0, h]),
  root;

var vis = d3.select("#network")
  .append("div").classed("svg-container", true)
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 600")
  .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
  .append("svg:g")
  //.attr("pointer-events", "all")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")")
//.call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1,8]).on("zoom",zoom));
//.call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
;

vis.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "svg-content-responsive")
  .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
  .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
  .attr("opacity", 0)

// draws edge
var diagonal = d3.linkVertical()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

root = treedata;
root.x0 = h / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// open or collaspe children of selected node
function toggleAll(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
    toggle(d);
  }
};
console.log(root)

// initialize the display to show a few nodes.
root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
//toggle(root.children[1]);
//toggle(root.children[9]);

update(root);

function update(source) {
  // how long animations last
  var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;
  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = hierarchy(root).children

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return "node-" + d.id;
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      toggle(d);
      update(d);
      // if (d['info']) {
      //   playvid(d['info']);
      // }
    });

  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  var nodeText = nodeEnter
    .append("svg:foreignObject")
    //.attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
    //.attr("dx", ".35em")
    //.attr("x", function(d) {
    //  return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    //})
    .attr("y", -30)
    .attr("x", -5)
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
    .attr('width', 300)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .append('xhtml:div')
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node-label" + " node-" + d.type
    })
    .classed("disabled", function(d) {
      return d.enable !== undefined && !d.enable;
    });

  //Enable node button
  nodeText.filter(function(d) {
      return d.enablable;
    })
    .append("input", ".")
    .attr("type", "checkbox")
    .property("checked", function(d) {
      return d.enable;
    })
    .on("change", toggleEnable, true)
    .on("click", stopPropogation, true);

  //Node label
  nodeText.append("span")
    .attr("class", "node-text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  //Edit node button
  nodeText.filter(function(d) {
      return d.editable;
    })
    .append("a")
    .attr("class", "node-edit")
    .on("click", onEditNode, true)
    .append("i")
    .attr("class", "fa fa-pencil");

  //Add node button
  nodeText.filter(function(d) {
      return d.addable;
    })
    .append("a")
    .attr("class", "node-add")
    .on("click", onAddNode, true)
    .append("i")
    .attr("class", "fa fa-plus");

  //Remove node button
  nodeText.filter(function(d) {
      return d.removable;
    })
    .append("a")
    .attr("class", "node-remove")
    .on("click", onRemoveNode, true)
    .append("i")
    .attr("class", "fa fa-times");

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting ndoes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);
  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links...
  var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(hierarchy(root).links(), function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at hte parent's previous position
  link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}
// Toggle children
function toggle(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
}

// zoom in / out
function zoom(d) {
  //vis.attr("transform", "transl3ate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  var nodes = vis.selectAll("g.node");
  nodes.attr("transform", transform);

  // Update the links...
  var link = vis.selectAll("path.link");
  link.attr("d", translate);

  // Enter any new links at hte parent's previous position
  //link.attr("d", function(d) {
  //      var o = {x: d.x0, y: d.y0};
  //      return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  //    });
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")";
}

function translate(d) {
  var sourceX = x(d.target.parent.y);
  var sourceY = y(d.target.parent.x);
  var targetX = x(d.target.y);
  var targetY = (sourceX + targetX) / 2;
  var linkTargetY = y(d.target.x0);
  var result = "M" + sourceX + "," + sourceY + " C" + targetX + "," + sourceY + " " + targetY + "," + y(d.target.x0) + " " + targetX + "," + linkTargetY + "";
  //console.log(result);

  return result;
}


function onEditNode(d) {
  var length = 9;
  var id = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, length);
  addChildNode(d.id, {
    "name": "new child node",
    "id": id,
    "type": "type2"
  });
  stopPropogation();
}

function onAddNode(d) {
  var length = 9;
  var id = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, length);
  addChildNode(d.id, {
    "name": "new child node",
    "id": id,
    "type": "type2"
  });
  stopPropogation();
}

function onRemoveNode(d) {
  var index = d.parent.children.indexOf(d);
  if (index > -1) {
    d.parent.children.splice(index, 1);
  }
  update(d.parent);
  stopPropogation();
}

function addChildNode(parentId, newNode) {
  var node = d3.select('#' + 'node-' + parentId);
  var nodeData = node.datum();
  if (nodeData.children === undefined && nodeData._children === undefined) {
    nodeData.children = [newNode];
  } else if (nodeData._children != null) {
    nodeData._children.push(newNode);
    toggle(nodeData);
  } else if (nodeData.children != null) {
    nodeData.children.push(newNode);
  }
  update(node);
  stopPropogation();
}

function toggleEnable(d) {
  d.enable = !d.enable;
  var node = d3.select('#' + 'node-' + d.id + " .node-label")
    .classed("disabled", !d.enable);
  stopPropogation();
}


function stopPropogation() {
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.node circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 160px;
  background: #d0dee7;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.node a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node a {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px
}

a.node-remove {
  color: red;
}

input+.node-text {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.node-label.node-type1 {
  background: coral;
}

.node-label.node-type2 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.node-label.node-type3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.node-label.disabled {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  color: #838383
}

.node text {
  font-size: 11px;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<div id="tree">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the diagonal function; I replaced it as well as other outdated chunks of code with code from this demo, https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd.